# Convert formula to value . Then, export a specific sheet as a xlsx file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Purpose:

- Convert the Google Sheets formula (cell reference) to the value (string and number) automatically.
- Export one sheet as an xlsx file via Google Apps Script.

Situation:

- Google Sheets: has Several Sheets.
- Google Apps Script: has code using "exportFormat" included URL.

```js
function emailWithConvertedFiles() {
  // Definition
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const params = { method: "get", headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, muteHttpExceptions: true };

 // File Extention
  const fileExtention =
    //"pdf";
    sheet.getRange(2,7).getValue();
    // "xlsx";

  // Sheet ID
  const sheetIdArray = [];
  sheetIdArray.push("1152040775");
  sheetIdArray.push("1154468777");
  sheetIdArray.push("54839846");

 
  //Blob
  const blobArray = [];
  //URL
  //TODO: Loop for each three sheets.
  for (i = 0; i < sheetIdArray.length; i++) {
    const url =
      "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="
      + ssId
      + "&exportFormat="
      + fileExtention
      + "&gid="
      + sheetIdArray[i] //Sheet ID
    //Blob
    blobArray.push(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(sheetIdArray[i] + "." + fileExtention));
    console.log(blobArray[i].getName() + " is added to the blobArray.");
  }

  // Mailapp
  const recipient = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  const subject = sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  const body = sheet.getRange(2, 4).getValue(); 
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, { attachments: blobArray });
  console.log("An Email with files is sent.");
}
```

Problem:

- An exported xlsx file has reference errors.
- Because the precedents are not included in the exported file.

The solutions I tried:

- To covert the reference, I used the TO_TEXT function & the INDIRECT function.

  - They didn't create any strings or numbers.

Comment:

Thank you for reading. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. I'll give it a try in few weeks and I'll let you know the result.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Sorry for a late reply. I'll give it a try in few weeks and I'll let you know the result.`, I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to export the specific sheets in a Google Spreadsheet as XLSX data.
- When the sheet is exported, you want to convert the formulas to the cell values.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Duplicate the active Spreadsheet as a temporal Spreadsheet.
  2. Retrieve the sheet names from the sheet IDs of `sheetIdArray`.
  3. Convert the formulas to the cell values for the specific sheets you want to export.
  4. Export the converted sheets as the blob of XLSX data.
  5. Delete the temporal Spreadsheet.

When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
//Blob
const blobArray = [];
//URL
//TODO: Loop for each three sheets.
for (i = 0; i < sheetIdArray.length; i++) {
  const url =
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="
    + ssId
    + "&exportFormat="
    + fileExtention
    + "&gid="
    + sheetIdArray[i] //Sheet ID
  //Blob
  blobArray.push(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(sheetIdArray[i] + "." + fileExtention));
  console.log(blobArray[i].getName() + " is added to the blobArray.");
}
```

To:

```
// 1. Duplicate the active Spreadsheet as a temporal Spreadsheet.
const tempSS = ss.copy("temp");
const tempSSId = tempSS.getId();

// 2. Retrieve the sheet names from the sheet IDs of `sheetIdArray`.
const sheetNames = ss.getSheets().reduce((ar, s) => {
  if (sheetIdArray.includes(s.getSheetId().toString())) ar.push(s.getSheetName());
  return ar;
}, []);

// 3. Convert the fomulas to the cell values for the specific sheets you want to export.
// 4. Export the converted sheets as the blob of XLSX data.
const blobArray = sheetNames.map(name => {
  const s = tempSS.getSheetByName(name);
  const r = s.getDataRange();
  r.copyTo(r, { contentsOnly: true });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + tempSSId + "&exportFormat=" + fileExtention + "&gid=" + s.getSheetId();
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(name + "." + fileExtention);
});

// 5. Delete the temporal Spreadsheet.
DriveApp.getFileById(tempSSId).setTrashed(true);
```

#### References:

- [copy(name) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String))
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: Thank you!! I will give it a try.

Comment: @Jinn Thank you for replying. If I misunderstood your question and my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.